# Converting one integer to list with one integer

Tags: python, list, integer

The prequel.
Do you know [fizz-buzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) task?
I use it for training in exceptions and testing with pytest.
And I think: why only two parameters?
With little modification I can use list of dividers and list of messages.
In normal case function takes `number_for_check`, `list_of_divider` and `list_of_messages`.
In real life there are many problems definitely but right now we ignore it.
What we should to do if user take only one divisor? Integer.
Convert it into list!

```python
   divider = 3
    if type(divider) == int:
        tempo = []
        tempo.append(divider)
        divider = tempo
    print(divider)
```

Is it good practice? How to do it more elegant? Or how to resolve the problem without implicit type conversion?

---

This is full implementation of this function. In the future it will be converted into class. But in the future.

```py
def perfect_oz_checker(num_for_check, dividers_array, message_array=['Fizz', 'Buzz', 'Juzz']) -> str:
    """
    Check the number and if it multiplies one of dividers return message like “Fizz”...

    Function takes:
    :param num_for_check: expected positive integer
    :param dividers_array: expected integer or array of integers
    :param message_array:  expected array of strings whose length is equal 
    to the length of the array of divisors
    :return: string
    """

    result_of_checking = ''

    if type(dividers_array) not in [int, list]:
        raise TypeError('You must use integer or list of integers')
    '''We need more Error handlers definitely'''

    if type(dividers_array) == int:
        tempo = []
        tempo.append(dividers_array)
        dividers_array = tempo

    for i in range(len(dividers_array)):
        result_of_checking += message_array[i] * (not num_for_check % dividers_array[i])

    if result_of_checking == '':
        result_of_checking = str(num_for_check)

    return result_of_checking
```

Comment: The general idea is fine. However you can replace the 3 lines of code that create the list with just `dividers_array = [dividers_array]`

Comment: You also should use `if isinstance(dividers_array, (int, list)):`

Comment: the best practice is not to accept an `int`, IMO.

Comment: @Barmar It's Alive! Thank you!!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. in real life another function or method will prepare data for main function. Right now it just takes me more cases for tests. And reason for convert function into class

Answer (score 0):

Answer for main question:
`dividers_array = [dividers_array]`
Thanks for [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

---

One more step to perfect code

```py
def perfect_oz_checker(num_for_check, dividers_array, message_array=['Fizz', 'Buzz', 'Juzz']) -> str:
    """
    Check the number and if it multiplies one of dividers return message like “Fizz”...

    Function takes:
    :param num_for_check: expected positive integer
    :param dividers_array: expected integer or array of integers
    :param message_array:  expected array of strings whose length is equal 
    to the length of the array of divisors
    :return: string
    """

    result_of_checking = ''

    if not isinstance(dividers_array, (int, list)):
        raise TypeError('You must use integer or list of integers')
    '''We need more Error handlers definitely'''


    '''I love Python'''
    if type(dividers_array) == int:
        dividers_array = [dividers_array]



    for i in range(len(dividers_array)):
        result_of_checking += message_array[i] * (not num_for_check % dividers_array[i])

    if result_of_checking == '':
        result_of_checking = str(num_for_check)

    return result_of_checking
```